# Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an application with Angular on the frontend and Dropwizard on the backend.

In this application I have a list of food intake, based on the product id in this intake I find a product object in a list of products (with the **getProduct(intake.productId)** function).

[image]

Such as this. However the three products you see are supposed to be different ones. The food intake has three different product ids. I can't seem to get the right values from the product lists (or they are being overwritten).

My console log does provide some help, it gives this error: 
**IntakeComponent.html:154 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '3275'. Current value: '3285'.** and I can see getProduct() is being called many more times than it should.

These are the relevant parts of my code:

intakeComponent.ts

```
product: Product;
products: Product[];

intakes: Intake[];

constructor(public userService: UserService, public clientService: ClientService, public intakeService: IntakeService, public productService: ProductService) {

}

ngOnInit() {

    this.getProducts();
    this.getIntake();

}

public getProducts() {

    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe(
        products => {
            this.products = products;
        }
    );
}

public getIntake() {

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.intakeService.getIntakePerDate(this.selectedClient.id, this.selectedDate).subscribe(
            intake => {
                this.intakes = intake;
            }
        );
    });
}

public getProduct(id: number) {

    if (this.products) {
        return this.products.find(product => product.id === id);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

intake.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let intake of intakes">

<td class="product">

    <input aria-label="Product" matInput [formControl]="myControl"
           [(ngModel)]="intake.productId" [value]="getProduct(intake.productId)?.description"
           (change)="editIntake(intake)" [matAutocomplete]="product"
           placeholder="Product" >

</td>
</tr>
```

I don't have that much experience with Angular yet. If anyone could help me out or provide tips that would be great!

Comment: Try to comment out some parts of your code, in order to make minimum reproducible bug - that will help you and others to find the error easier.

Answer (score 0):

`getProduct()` is called every time change detection runs. 
In development mode change detection always does a second turn in addition to the regular turn to check if the model changed in between.

In general try to avoid calling methods in value bindings (event bindings are fine of course)

```
[value]="getProduct(intake.productId)?.description"
```

If you think you must use method binding, ensure that the method doesn't do expensive work and that subsequent calls with the same parameters return the same object instance (equivalent value is not enough), otherwise you'll get the error you mention in your question.